# Error while copying google drive file using Google drive API V3

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am trying to copy the Google Drive file using Google Drive API V3.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy

This is my code to copy google drive file using c#. I can copy some files but for some files, I am failing to copy.

```
    public Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File copyDriveFiles(Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File file)
    {
        string strFileId = file.Id;
        //new file
        Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File copyFile = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
        copyFile.Name = file.Name;
        
        try
        {
            //copy request
            Google.Apis.Drive.v3.FilesResource.CopyRequest copyRequest = service.Files.Copy(copyFile, strFileId);
            copyRequest.SupportsAllDrives = true;
            copyFile = copyRequest.Execute();

            return copyFile;
        }
        catch (GoogleApiException ge)
        {
            throw ge;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I am getting an Internal error for some files as shown below.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "internalError",
    "message": "Internal Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 500,
  "message": "Internal Error"
 }
}
```

I will be grateful if anyone can explain the cause and any solution for this error.

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: Internal error isn't really much to go on, that's an error on Google's side. Please can you share your code and request?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have edited my question with uploading code to copy google drive files.

Comment: @TsheringChax For what kind of files are you getting this error, and does retrying always return this error? Are the files viewable/openable from the Drive UI?

Comment: Thank you @RafaGuillermo, for now, I am getting this error from CSV file with [MIME Type = "text/csv"]. But I have checked with other CSV files and it worked. Yes, I tried with the retry method too but the copy is failing. And to answer your last question. Yes, I can view the file from the Drive UI.

Comment: How big is this specific CSV file?

Comment: The size of the Specific CSV file is  283 bytes.

Comment: Are you still receiving this error?

Comment: Yes...and since I am not really sure about the cause of error I am trying to skip those errors and continue to copy other files.

Comment: Is the file on a shared Drive?

Comment: Yes, the file is on a shared Drive. Thank you

Comment: You need to set `supportsAllDrives` to true in your resource. See [`Files: copy`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy).

Comment: Thank you, but I tried with setting **supportsAllDrives** to **True** and the error is still occurring.

Comment: Can you show your code withh the full request, including `supportsAllDrives`?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo, I have edited the code(file copy request parts) in question. Thank you

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your code, if this is persistent then I would suggest contacting [G Suite support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)